# what is the difference between [photos] and [pictures]?

Tags: discussion, tags

Neither tag has a wiki. Surely one should be a synonym of the other?

[photos](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/photos) seems to have about double the questions of [pictures](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pictures). (Two questions have both.)

Comment: Good question. I think a photo is always a picture but the other way in not necessarly true. A picture can be a screen shot.

Comment: I would've thought [tag:photos] would relate to the photos app/hub, and pictures would be a synonym, with [tag:camera] to relate to *creating* photos